# Strategies for testing .ics or .ical file compatibility with iOS devices

Tags: ios, mobile-testing

I need to test .ics and .ical files for compatibility with the native calendar app on iOS devices.

If I purchase an iOS dev kit will this allow me to use the native calendar application under emulation?

Also, can the emulator run older versions of iOS?

Comment: Still don't know the answer to this question.